# Yammer - platform_social_buttons.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: yam.config is not a function

Tags: yammer

I have implemented a Yammer share button exactly according to https://developer.yammer.com/docs/share-button .

Right before  I have added:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js"></script>
```

yam.platform.yammerShare();

Then right after the opening , as a test, I added;

```
<span id="yj-share-button"></span>
```

The result - in Chrome and Firefox on Mac anyway:
"Uncaught TypeError: yam.config is not a function" (anonymous function) @ platform_social_buttons.min.js:2

So I thought; why not try loading "yam.platform.yammerShare();" on document ready.. but that made no difference.

I get no other JS errors, and this particular error occurs within platform_social_buttons.min.js. My site runs jQuery 2.1.4 if that matters, though https://developer.yammer.com/docs/share-button does not say anything about jQuery.

Why would this error occur? I am not using the JavaScript SDK, just the simple share button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include this script before platform_social_buttons.min.js

```
<script src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks. Odd that it is not mentioned on https://developer.yammer.com/docs/share-button .

Comment: Maybe they suppose that's already referenced on the same page. I've suggested an edit to the page.

Comment: thanks, because it really is not obvious from that page